# How to display a specific part of a website

Tags: css

My current page looks like this:
[image: Webpage]

and I want to cut the left and right when the display gets smaller, like this:[image]
I tried to use the object fit property to crop the image but didn't came to far with that.
My main problem is that there is to much room under the image when looked at with a small screen size.[image]

Here's my code.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Arcane</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://www.dafontfree.net/embed/ZnJpei1xdWFkcmF0YS10dC1yZWd1bGFyJmRhdGEvMjUvZi8xMjU2NDIvRnJpelF1YWRyYXRhVFQudHRm" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body id="index">
    <div class="bgImage">
      <img src="/Img/Arcane_Title_Text.png" alt="ARCANE" id="Arcane">
      <p class="fan">a fanmade quiz</p>
      <img src="/Img/qejzvmh681181.jpg" alt="LEAGUE WM IMAGE" id="leagueImg">
      <a href="about.html" id="startLink"><b>START NOW</b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hide_in_rice/"><img src="/Img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram" id="instaL"></a>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&family=Roboto:wght@100;300&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#index {
  background-color: rgb(6, 1, 15);
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.bgImage {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#leagueImg {
  width: 100%;
  
}
#startLink {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #dbb391;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
}
#startLink:hover {
    color: rgb(253, 251, 231);
}

#instaL {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2%;
  left: 48%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

#Arcane {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 15%;
    max-width: 30%;
}
.fan {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 25%;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #f7d9bf;
}
```

With some help I could make it work for the most part (here my web on a galaxy s5)
[image]
but there is still the same problem for different screen sizes ( my web on an IPad Pro)
[image]
I tried to set a min-height for the website, trough putting all my elements into a container and restraining the height, what resulted in a mess.

Comment: That's a pretty vague way of just saying that you want to center the content & background image. It sounds to me like you want `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center center` (or maybe `center top`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the ways to do it is simply  by giving the image a **min-height** and using the **object-position** property to center it and **object-fit** of **cover**.

you should specify the **min-height** depending on your image by testing.

```
img#leagueImg{
    width:100%;
    min-height:400px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 0%;
}
```

and here is a snippet:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&family=Roboto:wght@100;300&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#index {
  background-color: rgb(6, 1, 15);
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.bgImage {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
/*
#leagueImg {
  width: 100%;
  
}/* This no longer needed */
*/
#startLink {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #dbb391;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
}
#startLink:hover {
    color: rgb(253, 251, 231);
}

#instaL {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2%;
  left: 48%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

#Arcane {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 15%;
    max-width: 30%;
}
.fan {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 25%;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #f7d9bf;
}

img#leagueImg{
    width:100%;
    min-height:400px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Arcane</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://www.dafontfree.net/embed/ZnJpei1xdWFkcmF0YS10dC1yZWd1bGFyJmRhdGEvMjUvZi8xMjU2NDIvRnJpelF1YWRyYXRhVFQudHRm" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body id="index">
    <div class="bgImage">
      <img src="https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Arcane-Logo.png" alt="ARCANE" id="Arcane">
      <p class="fan">a fanmade quiz</p>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Herjangsfjorden_%26_Ofotfjorden%2C_wide%2C_2009_09.jpg" alt="LEAGUE WM IMAGE" id="leagueImg">
      <a href="about.html" id="startLink"><b>START NOW</b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hide_in_rice/"><img src="/Img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram" id="instaL"></a>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

***EDIT:***

As I understood from your comment, what you're trying to achieve can be done using these **3** methods:

1. **Not Recommended**: Making media queries for a few screen sizes and specify a suitable image height for each.
2. **Recommended somehow:** Using a single media query at the screen size which you wish to apply this crop and use two images one for big screens and one (Cropped) for small screens.
3. You could use JavaScript to switch between the two images easily but the effect will be applied after page loads, you may find a way around it.

There's a few other ways, it's even better if you replace your **img** with any  element with a **background-image**, ***but*** here's the ***implementation for your situation***:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&family=Roboto:wght@100;300&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#index {
  background-color: rgb(6, 1, 15);
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.bgImage {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#leagueImg {
  width: 100%;
}
#startLink {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #dbb391;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
}
#startLink:hover {
    color: rgb(253, 251, 231);
}

#instaL {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2%;
  left: 48%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

#Arcane {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 15%;
    max-width: 30%;
}
.fan {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 25%;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #f7d9bf;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
  img#leagueImg{
    background: url("https://antiexam.com/img/external/cropped.png");
    object-position: 200vw;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100vw;
    background-position:center bottom;
    /* chose whether to crop the top or bottom of the image*/
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Arcane</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://www.dafontfree.net/embed/ZnJpei1xdWFkcmF0YS10dC1yZWd1bGFyJmRhdGEvMjUvZi8xMjU2NDIvRnJpelF1YWRyYXRhVFQudHRm" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body id="index">
    <div class="bgImage">
      <img src="https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Arcane-Logo.png" alt="ARCANE" id="Arcane">
      <p class="fan">a fanmade quiz</p>
      <img src="https://antiexam.com/img/external/big.png" alt="LEAGUE WM IMAGE" id="leagueImg">
      <a href="about.html" id="startLink"><b>START NOW</b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hide_in_rice/"><img src="/Img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram" id="instaL"></a>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Not the best implantation of course but works for your situation easily.

***ANOTHER EDIT:***
Here's the javascript method as I think it's the best one except it needs to wait for the page to load, I hope you find a way around it.

JS:

```
function checkWidth(){
    let width = window.screen.width;
    if(width < 1024){
        document.getElementById('leagueImg').setAttribute('src', 'https://antiexam.com/img/external/cropped.png')
    }else{
        document.getElementById('leagueImg').setAttribute('src', 'https://antiexam.com/img/external/big.png')
    }
}
window.addEventListener('resize', checkWidth);
checkWidth();
```

***HTML and CSS are same as your initial ones.***

Comment: Works like a charm, but there is still the same problem when I view this page on a IPad sized screen. I tried giving the whole website a min height but that didn't work. I uploaded a image for this in my question above.

Comment: I edited the answer, not an optimal way to do it, but ready to use on your HTML structure. You only have to make another image by cropping your image using any photo editor.

Comment: I'll look into your JS solution, but I had another idea that also sounds plausable. The IPad proplem occurs due to the insane screen size. It easily fills the min-height of 500 px and shows the image uncropped. My idea is to change the min-height to a percent value of like 75 to garantee a cropped image no matter what screensize the user might have. The idea is there, but it doesn't work quite as expected, only changing the min-height value did not work. Do you have any idea how to implement this? I'm using the initial code.

Comment: You can use relative units for example (70vh) means 70% of viewport height. but this will not give you what you imagine. there is no way to get the perfect outcome that you wan't unless you apply the second solution with any element not (img).

Comment: Fascinatingly, the solution with the 70vh gave me my hoped for outcome. Appriciate your help. Cheers